# What am I missing in this Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to learn Powershell for more automation in my daily job and have very little scripting or coding background. I am attempting to use this script to pull motherboard information from systems, eventually to poll all 600+ systems on a particular subnet. I am getting an error and not sure how to correct.

I have Googled this error message and searched here, but not finding an exact match for what I am doing wrong. This is probably a simple fix, if I knew what I were looking for.

```
$strComputer = "." 

$colItems = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_MotherboardDevice" -namespace "root\CIMV2" ` 
-computername $strComputer
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
*-computername : The term '-computername' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:4 char:1
+ -computername $strComputer*
```

Comment: Don't put a space after the backquote if you're trying to continue the line.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that there is a SPACE character, or other whitespace, after the GRAVE ACCENT (backtick) indicating line continuation. Please remove any characters after the GRAVE ACCENT.

Answer (score 1):

-computername sohuld be on the same line as the rest - the error suggests it isn't escaped properly to be on 2 lines - try:

```
$strComputer = "."

$colItems = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_MotherboardDevice" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computername $strComputer 

$colitems
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for the answers, you were correct, I had a space after the grave accent. I removed the space and it works fine now. My apologies for the amateur mistake.

Comment: No need to apologize! You asked a question and you did it properly, which a lot of new users fail to do! You posted your code, asked your question, and provided the results/errors. Welcome to SO!